# Trying to use attr_accessor value in model in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, attr-accessor

I have a model where I create an attr_accessor:

```
attr_accessor :schedule_date
```

In my form I have a field:

```
<%= f.text_field :schedule_date, label: 'Date', required: true %>
```

And now after submitting the form I want to use this field in my model to make some calculation.

The problem is that schedule_date is undefined in my model. Just to test it I am trying to raise an error with the value of the field:

My model looks like this:

```
class Ride < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :schedule_date, :schedule_time
  raise schedule_date
end
```

But when submitting the form I get:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `schedule_date'

Why can't I use my attr_accessor value inside my model?

Answer (score 1):

You can only call it via the object itself or @schedule_date

```
obj.schedule_date
```

because

`attr_accessor :schedule_date` is simply a shortcut for the following:

```
def schedule_date=(var)
  @schedule_date = var
end

def schedule_date
  @schedule_date
end
```

Update

```
 ride = Ride.new()
 ride.schedule_date
```

Comment: This gives me: undefined local variable or method `obj'

Comment: It was just an example we need to create new Ride object for it